# Using double underscore as parameter name in class member functions

Tags: c++, oop

I working on my own c++ library project. So I saw the source code of different `std::` header files I saw all the parameters names are mostly `__pos` (having two consecutive underscores) I found few answers in StackOverflow that it is not a best practice to name variables having (__) double underscore followed by lower case letters as they are reserved. so I was wondering will it be a problem if i used double underscore on my function parameter name.

**Edit** :
yes, it is an open-source project and has no potential users. I am doing it for college purposes and myself.
if using double underscore are not a good practice then what should be followed to distinguish between private data members and functions.

Comment: *so i was wondering will it be a problem if i used double underscore on my function parameter name* -- Why take a chance?  Just don't use double underscore names anywhere.

Comment: Is your C++ library opensource? If yes, where is the source code... If no, who would be the potential users?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#In_declarations): `"the identifiers with a double underscore anywhere are reserved"`.  See also [lex.name#3.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/lex.name#3.1)

Comment: *what should be followed to distinguish between private data members and functions.* -- One coding standard is to have member variables prefaced with `m_`.

Comment: Names that contain two consecutive underscores and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't define them in your code.